# How to inject into dynamically created use cases (android, clean architecture, dagger2)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I'm creating an Android app and want to comply to clean architecture.
For example, I have an activity which has a presenter which creates use cases. In that inner layer, I have a repository interface (which is known by the use cases) which is implemented by a concrete repository, lets call it repsoitoryImpl (which is not known by the uses cases). What I did in previous projects was to create the presenter and the repositoryImpl in the activity, and pass the repositoryImpl as a repository to the presenter. The presenter can then, whenever there is an action coming from the activity (e.g. a button press) create a new use case and pass the repository to it.

This works, but a) the constructors of the use cases can become very long and b) the UI has knowledge of all other "outer" things, e.g. the repositoryImpl. So I thought DI to the rescue! And started to try out Dagger 2. However, my current solution does not seem to be "correct". What I would have liked is that I can just have an @inject annotated repository in a usecase and a repositoryImpl gets injected. However I found that, at the beginning of the "injection chain" I have to call inject() on the dagger component. In most of the examples, this is done in the activity. But then I would have to inject the presenter in the activity and the usecase into the presenter to be able to inject things into the use case. Is this correct? The problem is that I want to create the use cases dynamically with different parameters and not inject them.

So my current solution is to have the dagger "AppComponent" as a static field in the Android Application class and then in my use cases I call

```
Application.component.inject(this)
```

which allows me to inject things in the use case. But then the use cases have a dependency to dagger which doesn't comply to clean architecture. Because framework dependencies should only appear in the outer layer.

Is there a common solution to this problem? Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at constructor injection? `.inject()` should primarily be used to inject Android Framework components, and not every single class that you write

Comment: why do you need to create your use cases dynamically? what are the conditions to provide the different use cases?

Comment: @Benjamin 
I want to create them dynamically because they have dynamic parameters. For example, I want to call `new CreateHouseUseCase(doors, windows, callback).execute()`      
@DavidMedenjak Yes I know constructor injection but when I create the use case "manually", the parameters are not injected, are they?

Comment: No, fields will not be injected if you create the object yourself. But you can inject a `Provider<MyUseCase>` in your presenter, then call `provider.get()` to create a new use case object (that will be constructor injected)

Comment: Indeed, if you construct your object manually, nothing will be injected. Have you tried constructor injection? Just create the appropriate methods i.e. `providesDoor()` and `providesWindows()` for example to provide the needed dependencies used by your use cases.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The doors, windows and callback were supposed to be things I don't want to inject. The use case could for example call `repository.addHouse(new House(doors, windows)); callback.onSuccess()`, were only the repository should be injected. Especially the callback for example of course depends on who has created the use case.
@DavidMedenjak when using this `provider.get()`, can I pass dynamic arguments? And get a use case which has both, these passed arguments and the injected things? Yes I think that's the answer to my question then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As u already pointed out in clean architecture use cases must not know about DI frameworks - even decorating use cases with framework specific attributes would be a smell.

As discussed here: [How to handle UseCase Interactor constructors that have too many dependency parameters in DDD w/ Clean Architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141142/how-to-handle-usecase-interactor-constructors-that-have-too-many-dependency-para) having too many constructor parameters is usually an indicator that the use case is "doing too much". U should consider splitting them.

Furthermore the interfaces used by a use case to access "the details" (repository, external services and systems) should be designed in a way that they are most convenient for the use case. That means instead of having multiple repository interfaces and multiple service interfaces passed to a use case u could consider using façade pattern and design one or two interfaces which are more convenient for the use cases which then "aggregate" the work with the different repositories/services. This will also reduce the number of parameters passed to the constructor.

According to clean architecture the "composition" of ur application happens in the "main component" - a class living in the frameworks circle. There are objects are created and injected. If u want to create use cases dynamically u could have a factory pattern.